# Text inside container keeps floating a bit to the top

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin, center

I have a problem with positioning a text inside its container.
I want to keep it exactly in the middle, so both justifying and aligning.
So I would like it to look like so:

[image]

What I do is:

```html
        <div className="view-container">
            <div className="view-icon-container">
                <img className="view-icon" width={icon.size} height={icon.size} src={icon.src} />
            </div>
            <div className="view-text-container">
                <p className="view-text">Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

with the following styling:

```css
.view-container {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.view-icon {
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.view-text {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.view-text-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.view-icon-container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Notice please the `7px` margin-top applied to the `view-text`. My issue is that without it, the text goes to the top a bit, so it looks like so:

[image]

My question is: What is causing this margin, or padding to appear? Where does it hide in my CSS?

Comment: You should change the attribute name className to class in your HTML. And why you added position: absolute and margin-top: 7px to the .view-text element? Its parent should handle the positioning with align-items and justify-content. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I added the margin-top as a workaround for the issue I asked about (please read the whole post).
And yes - it's parent should handle the position, but my main issue is, that whatever I set to the styles to whatever container, it just won't align the text to the center.

Comment: @knospe - He says that without the 7px, it is not centered!

Comment: I think the issue is using the p tag.  replace it with a div.  Most tags have predefined defaults.  You have probably not cancelled some of them when you are using the paragraph.

Comment: If it isn't the p element, then you need to post more of your code so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I think that changing the position attribute from "absolute" to "relative" in the view-text class is the solution. If yes I'll make a separate answer to this question.

Comment: @Devolux Setting it to `relative` instead of `absolute` does not also fix the problem of extra padding on top.

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, changing the `p` to `div` does remove the extra padding on top - this is the correct answer.
Please post it as an answer so I can officially accept it.
Thank you!

Comment: @BartoszKlonowski i didn't thought you were open to change the HTML element. In this case i suggest you to use span not p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is using the **p** tag. replace it with a **div**. Most tags have predefined defaults. You have probably not cancelled some of them when you are using the paragraph.

If you right-click on the page and select **Inspect**. Select the p element.  On the right-hand side you will see your attributes and the browser's defaults.  This may or may not be the [HTML Specification defaults](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).  And these may change over time.

However, if you are working on margins etc, then you could start off by specifying

```css
margin:0
padding:0
```

Comment: Let me ask: Would it be possible for you to elaborate about how to cancel the default behavior of `p` in this case?